# Applications of Elimination theory

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Elimination Theory
deals with elimination of a subset of variables from a given set of polynomial equations
and finding the reduced set of polynomial equations (not involving the eliminated variables).What is the importance and applications of Elimination theory?

Comment: Example application: intersection of two conics (hence also distance of a point to a conic).

Answer (score 1):

Elimination Theory for polynomial equations is useful in Computer Aided Geometric Design. See for instance

> ["Algebraic Methods for Computer Aided Geometric Design"](https://students.cs.byu.edu/~tom/557/text/grobner.pdf) by Thomas W. Sederberg and Jianmin Zheng, a chapter in [*Handbook of Computer Aided Geometric Design*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444511041).